# Incorrect spacing between cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` containing `UICollectionViewCells` which have `UIButton`s inside of them for content.

However the spacing is between each cell is incorrect incorrect. The cells in the collection view are not specific in size, as its supposed to be a list of tags which will obviously vary in length.

Heres what it looks like:

[image]

The horizontal spacing between each cell is completely incorrect as they vary from row to row.

The code for the cell:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var wordsCollection: UICollectionView!
    var items = ["test", "this", "word view", "like", "collection", "testing", "give", "this", "testing", "test", "test", "this", "word view", "like", "collection", "testing", "give", "this", "testing", "test", "test", "this", "word view", "like", "collection"]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "wordCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! WordCell
        cell.wordButton.setTitle(items[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.wordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        if(indexPath.row % 3 == 0){
            cell.wordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
        cell.wordButton.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.wordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        cell.wordButton.sizeToFit()

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let flowLayout = wordsCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout { flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width:1, height:1) }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Language is Swift 4 and Im targeting iOS 10.3.

Comment: you havent implemented the UICollectionview's Flow Layout delegate, then implement the method interItemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing

Answer (score 1):

Implement : `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

and then:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return THE_SPACING_AMOUNT
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return SPACING_BETWEEN_ROWS
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Just given it a shot and it has improved but its still off for some rows. https://i.imgur.com/yvLAu0s.png

Comment: are you trying to align them in anyway ? otherwise it will just attempt to fill the row, im guessing your using autalayout in the cells, try to set the priority of the leading/trailig to 500

Comment: Sadly neither makes any difference. I think Autolayout is enabled for the cells because of `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width:1, height:1)` in my `viewDidLoad()` func.

Comment: sorry I think theres some confusion i meant inside your WordCell, the leading and trailing constraints on the label to priority 500

Comment: No worries! Yeah sorry I meant I had tried the constraints on the label for priority 500